# Cannot Pass user_id as Param after locating User via Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My apologies in advance if the title of this post is not clear, I was having difficulty explaining the issue I am having. I have an app that allows user to create Goals. I am attempting to create a Collaboration model so that users may share their Goals with one another. To do so, I created a Collaboration model that belongs to the User and Goal model and stores goal_id and user_id to represent the access that users have to other goals.

I created a form in Goal#show that allows the user to enter the email address of the user they would like to share with. I will use that email, grab the user_id from the associated record and create the Collaboration record entry. I am having trouble going from getting the User Email to getting the ID and passing that as a Param. Code is posted below.

CollaborationsController.rb

```
class CollaborationsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @goal = Goal.find(params[:goal_id])
        @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
        #@user=User.find(params[:email])
      if @user
            @collaboration = @goal.collaborations.create(collaboration_params)
            if @collaboration.save
                flash[:notice] = "User successfully added to goal."
            else
                flash[:error] = "There was a problem adding user. Please try again."
            end
        else
            flash[:error] = "Sorry that wasn't a valid username. Please try again."
        end
        redirect_to goal_path(@goal)
    end

    def collaboration_params
      params.require(:collaboration).permit(:user_id, :goal_id)
  end

end
```

collaboration/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @goal, @goal.collaborations.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
  <%= form.label :email %>
  <%= form.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= form.submit %>
  <p>
<% end %>
```

Form Data from Developer Tools:

```
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: RXa9u10cLdw1FK29hOly33wWDN+dDd5NTtvZ/yYbKfMJ6RhHw+nV8/OgiFbQ+raRcNzbbWItCct7lv+A3CmINw==
collaboration[email]: [actualemailofuser]
commit: Create Collaboration
```

The email address is submitted and handled. How do I get from finding the User record with that email to getting the user_id from that record to submitting it as a param?

Comment: give `@collaboration.user_id = current_user.id` before the line `if @collaboration.save`

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred because I was not successfully passing the :email parameter into the Controller method create.

Here is the the working code:

collaborations_controller.rb

```
class CollaborationsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @goal = Goal.find(params[:goal_id])
        @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
      if @user
            @collaboration = Collaboration.new(goal_id: @goal.id, user_id: @user.id)
            if @collaboration.save
                flash[:notice] = "User successfully added to goal."
            else
                flash[:error] = "There was a problem adding user. Please try again."
            end
        else
            flash[:error] = "Sorry that wasn't a valid username. Please try again."
        end
        redirect_to goal_path(@goal)
    end

    def collaboration_params
      params.require(:collaboration).permit(:user_id, :goal_id, :email)
  end

end
```

collaborations/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @goal, @goal.collaborations.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
 </p>
  <p>
  <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```